# Why is using string substitiution to form a regex not working?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, substitution

I have a regular expression for use with awk to find any of the specified words in a line of a file. It looks like this `awk "/word1/||/word2/||/word3/" filename`. As an alternative, I have been trying to specify the words like this `WORDS="word1 word2 word3"` and then use bash string substitution to form the regular expression to pass to awk.

I've tried numerous ways of doing this to no avail. awk simply dumps the contents of the entire file or spits out some complaint about the regex form.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="myfile"
WORDS="word1 word2 word3"

# use BASH string substitution to obtain the regex which should look like this:
# "/word1/||/word2/||/word3/"

REGEX=\"/${WORDS// //||/}/\"

awk ${REGEX} $FILE
```

I'm fairly sure it has to do with quoting and I've tried various methods using echo and back ticks and can get it *look* right (when echoed) but when actually trying to use it, it fails.

Comment: That's both a strange use of awk and a strange-looking regex combination. You should be trying to get `/a|b|c/` (and using an extended `grep`)

Comment: I tried this in cygwin: try to prepend regex' special chars with "\" sign. This command works for me: `awk /\(def\|abc\)/ abc.txt` - finds all lines which have "def" or "abc" in them

Comment: @Mat. Thanks. Search results lead me to awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
REGEX=\"/${WORDS// //||/}/\"
```

with:

```
REGEX="/${WORDS// //||/}/"
```

Note that there is no need to escape double quotes since they are not really part of the regular expression.